# How to include FluentDom library into my PHP file?

Tags: php, json, xml

**Precondition**: have Amazon MWS demo files written in PHP. Amazon responds results in XML.
My tool, which will work with Amazon's output, works fine only with json.

Need to convert output from Amazon into json.

1. I downloaded FluentDOM from here https://github.com/ThomasWeinert/FluentDOM
2. Unzipped it close to my script
3. Tried to include FluentDom library in my files

Path to my script:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\src\MarketplaceWebServiceProducts\Samples\MyGetASINdetails.php

Path to FluentDom:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\src\src\FluentDOM.php

I tried to connect library in this way

```
include('../../src/FluentDOM.php');
```

to convert from XML to Json in this way (saw in other thread on StackOverflow):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
//      echo $dom->saveXML();
$json = new \FluentDOM\Serializer\Json\RabbitFish($dom->saveXML());
$object = json_decode($json);
echo "<pre>" . print_r( $object, true) . "</pre>";
echo "<script>console.log({$json})</script>";
```

when run, got

> Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\src\FluentDOM.php on line 43

Line 43 of FluentDOM.php:

```
public static function load($source, string $contentType = 'text/xml', array $options = []): \FluentDOM\DOM\Document {
```

Comment: Looks like you are running on PHP5 but the code use you try to execute is PHP7 (there are type hints in function params)

Comment: I checked and you're right:  USER - PC@SASHA c:\xampp
# php -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 15:12:06)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

Comment: Installed XAMMP with PHP 7.*. Became better but not so much. 

    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'FluentDOM\Serializer\Json\RabbitFish' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\MarketplaceWebServiceProducts\Samples\MyGetASINdetails.php:118 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\src\MarketplaceWebServiceProducts\Samples\MyGetASINdetails.php(85): invokeListMatchingProducts(Object(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client), Object(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ListMatchingProductsRequest)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\MarketplaceWebServiceProducts\Samples\MyGetASINdetails.php on line 118

Answer (score 0):

FluentDOM 7 requires PHP >= 7.0. You could use an older version. FluentDOM 6.2 requires PHP >= 5.6

However FluentDOM is a Composer package. You really should use Composer to add it to your project. It will install the compatible version (if you define it) and take care of the autoloader (your current error).

FluentDOM 5.3 was the last version that included a "_require.php" to support a manual install.